# How can I render few data of my tables only once and few other in a loop in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, ado.net

This is my model where I want to retrieve these data from the database. In the database, the data in the columns except for ITName, qty, and rate don't have distinct data so I want to avoid repetitive data being displayed on the view page.

Do I have to use get enumerable method in model to be able to retrieve data in a loop in the view page

```
namespace DateList.Models
{
    public class list
    {

        public string NepaliInvoiceDate { get; set; }
        public int salesMasterId { get; set; }
        public DateTime BillDate { get; set; }
        public decimal TermAmount { get; set; }
        public decimal NetAmount { get; set; }
        public decimal totaldiscount { get; set; }
        public string ITName { get; set; }
        public decimal qty { get; set; }
        public decimal rate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the controller where I get single data by using FirstOrDefault with the method I created in the Service. Here If I use FirstOrDefault then I get the first data of the different rows that share the same ID. To get data of a few rows only once and other data in a loop do I have to make changes in my Controller method as well?

```
[Route("/list/Temp/{id?}")]
        public ActionResult Temp(int id)
        {

            var dl = list.GetTemp(id).FirstOrDefault();
            //var dll = list.GetTemp(id);
            /*if (dl == null)
            {
                TempData["InfoMessage"] = "Not" + id.ToString();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }*/

            return View(dl);
        }


        //POST: ListByDate
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Temp")]
        public ActionResult Temp(List list)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    var dl = list.GetAllList();

                }

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                TempData["Error Message"] = ex.Message;
                return View();
            }
        }
```

This is the Service code where I have created the method to get the data. In this method, I can retrieve a single data if I create a  view page with a Details Template using FirstOrDeault in the controller and I also can retrieve all data by using the method as it is with List Template in the View page but what I want here is the combination of both as I need few data only once and other data more than once. Note that a few columns have the same data in the rows but a few columns have different data. The bottom line is that I don't want to display duplicates as  I want distinct data to be displayed in my View page.

```
public List<list> GetTemp(int id)

        {

            List<list> listList = new List<list>();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(this.conn))
            {
                
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_list", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@smid", id);
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                conn.Close();


                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    listList.Add(new list
                    {
                        NepaliInvoiceDate = Convert.ToString(dr["NepaliInvoiceDate"]),
                        salesMasterId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["salesMasterId"]),
                        BillDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["BillDate"]),
                        TermAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["TermAmount"]),
                        NetAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["NetAmount"]),
                        totaldiscount = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["totaldiscount"])
                       /* ITName = Convert.ToString(dr["ITName"]),
                        qty = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["qty"]),
                        rate = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["rate"]),*/


                    });
                }
            }
            return listList;
        }
```

I want to display my data on my view page where I want to render a few data only once and others in a loop.

In this view, the main problem I am facing is that I can't use the for each loop as I have passed FirstOrDefault with my method in my controller. AS in the code below except for ITName, qty, and rate other data are not kept in the loop as they have the same data. In the View page, I can retirve data of one record if I use FirstOrDefault and all record with simply the method passed but what I want is to retrieve that data of duplicate record only once and distinct data in a loop. So what changes I need to make to be able to use the foreach loop

```
@model DateList.Models.list

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Temp";
}

<h2>Temp</h2>


<div>
    <h4>list</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NepaliInvoiceDate)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.NepaliInvoiceDate)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.salesMasterId)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.salesMasterId)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BillDate)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.BillDate)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TermAmount)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TermAmount)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NetAmount)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.NetAmount)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.totaldiscount)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.totaldiscount)
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>


<table class="table">
    <tr>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ITName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.qty)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.rate)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
         
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ITName)
            </td>
           *<td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.qty)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.rate)
            </td>
            
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

This is my view page where I want to render the ITName, rate, and qty in a loop as they don't have duplicate data but when I try to do this enumerable error is thrown.
How can I achieve it or where do I have to make changes? In my database, there are different entries of data with the same ID but other rows have different value so I don't want to display the duplicate data on the view side

Comment: You should give discriptive names to your classes. "list" does not describe what this class represents. Also try to keep consistent coding style. Some of your class properties start with lowercase letter and other with uppercase. In C# it is common to use PascalCase for class and property names. Just my advice :)

Comment: I will follow your advice as I am new to C#. I didn't get what I should do to get the output can you elaborate

Comment: Do you use `Asp.Net Core` or just `Asp.Net`?